# CS0103 C# The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Well,

I have written JsonResult funtion. But i get the following error:

> CS0103 C# The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

I cant find solution to it... plzz help?

```
public JsonResult DoUserExist(string Emailaddress)
{
    bool ch = false;
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FreelanceDBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetCities", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (rdr != null)
        {
            ch = true;
        }
    }
    return Json(ch,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: Your return object needs needs to be the same as the return type of the function.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JsonResult return Json in ASP.NET CORE 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101100/jsonresult-return-json-in-asp-net-core-2-1)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I got it !

I have forgotten to derive my class from Controller class

```
public class User: Controller
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was deriving from ControllerBase (probably based on some previous template). Changing to Controller solved it!

Comment: I also needed to include the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc package as well.
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`

Answer (score 9):

Page must be derived from Controller class to
Json () and JsonResult() part by 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

If you are using Razor page model then you can face this issue.
I got it after too much time spending.

You can also change your page derived from Controller instead of pagemodel like this  public class User: Controller

Comment: They could DRAMATICALLY improve the error message here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first try this,
in your controller it should be `ActionResult` not the `JsonResult` and you should pass object as the data.

You can get string output as follow. In here getCities is the model similar to the table fields.

```
 public string DoUserExist(string Emailaddress)
    {
        bool ch = false;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FreelanceDBCS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetCities", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    con.Open();    
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<getCities> _getCities= new List<getCities>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                getCities cities= new getCities();
                cities.Data.Add(int.Parse(reader["col2"].ToString()));
                cities.Data.Add(int.Parse(reader["col3"].ToString()));
                cities.Data.Add(int.Parse(reader["col4"].ToString()));

                _getCities.Add(cities);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            jsonString = jss.Serialize(_getCities);
        }
    }

return jsonString;  
}
```