# System.Web.Helpers.Json is a 'type' but it is used like a 'variable'

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to return a list as an array to angular application using web service method. But when i'm doing so, i'm getting error as 'System.Web.Helpers.Json is a 'type' but it is used like a 'variable'' though i have added all the namespaces. Here is my code

```
[WebMethod]
    public JsonResult helloworld(int id)
    {
        var items = _db.Items.Where(p => p.CategoryTypeID == id).Torray();
        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Please help me through it or any other alternate.

Comment: The `Json`'s J should be Capital. You can add content type also . `return Json(Result, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: actually 'j' is capital itself, i just missed while typing @UnknownUser

Comment: Have you added `System.Web.Mvc` dll in your `project refrences`?

Comment: Yes, i have added @UnknownUser

Comment: did that helped?

Comment: actually i have added all the necessary namespaces but the error remains same @UnknownUser

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272203/cs0103-c-sharp-the-name-json-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string helloworld(int id)
{
    var items = _db.Items.Where(p => p.CategoryTypeID == id).Torray();
    return new JavaScriptSerializar().Serialize(items);
}
```

Try to use this code.