# .net Core class to get parameters and return as json

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

There is a case where I should take parameters from MVC web page like : 
DateFrom, DateTo, Contract and Database and return that in JSON format.

I need to write that class in .NET Core . 
Any help, as I worked only in ASP .net

```
public class FilterController : Controller
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public FilterController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IActionResult Index([FromServices]IConnectionStringService service, int id)
    {
        List<ConnectionStringDto> list = new List<ConnectionStringDto>();

        if (service != null)
        {
            list = service.GetConnectionStringList(id);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                list.First(x => x.ConnectionStringId == id).IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(list);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RunFilter([FromServices]IConnectionStringService service, List<ConnectionStringDto> list)
    {
        list = new List<ConnectionStringDto>(); 
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

Code from Filter, where form should be. Form is not yet done.

Comment: You can use the [JsonResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1) class for sending your complex list as JSON object to your client something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101719/7177029).

Comment: could you provide some code from the source page? is it a form? the more code you provide the easier it is for people to form an answer (although Ahmed's answer below might actually cover what you need)

Comment: @scgough Source code added. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return `JsonResult`

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDate")]
    public JsonResult GetDate(DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo)
    {
        return Json(new { DateFrom = DateFrom, DateTo = DateTo });
    }
```