# C# WebAPI return JSON data

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I am absolutely new to C# and I'm trying to learn WebApi. I have `DataAccess.csproj` which contains `List` which is as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DataAccess.BO;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class PersonDataAccess
    {
        #region Data
        private static readonly List<Person> Data = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person
            {
                Id = 8,
                GivenName = "Trinh",
                FamilyName = "Montejano",
                BossId = 3,
                Title = "Tech Manager",
                Gender = Gender.Unspecified,
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("1966-09-27")
            },
            new Person
            {
                Id = 1,
                GivenName = "Winfred",
                FamilyName = "Fetzer",
                BossId = null,
                Title = "CEO",
                Gender = Gender.Unspecified,
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("1927-01-29")
            },
            new Person
            {
                Id = 2,
                GivenName = "Erich",
                FamilyName = "Dandrea",
                BossId = 1,
                Title = "VP of Marketing",
                Gender = Gender.Male,
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("1927-08-20")
            },
        };
#endregion

        //TODO:  Implement whatever methods are needed to access the data.
    }
}
```

and I want to return data in raw JSON like

```
{
    "User": {
        "Id" : "1",
        "FirstName" : "Winfred",
        "LastName" : "Fetzer",
        "BossName" : null,
        "Title" : "CEO",
        "DateOfBirth" : "1927-01-29",
        "Gender" : "Female",
        "Addresses" : [{
            "Id" : 1,
            "Street" :  "62 Durham Court",
            "City" : "Garfield",
            "State" : "NJ",
            "Zip" : "07026"
        },{
            "Id" : 2,
            "Street" :  "179 Cambridge Court",
            "City" : "Chippewa Falls",
            "State" : "WI",
            "Zip" : "54729"
        },{
            "Id" : 3,
            "Street" :  "573 Route 5",
            "City" : "Memphis",
            "State" : "TN",
            "ZipCode" : "38106"
        }]
    }
}
```

The "Addresses" object is like `PersonDataAccess`.

My `UserContrller.cs` is this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using DataAccess;

namespace SrEngineer.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/v1/user")]
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {

    }

}
```

So, far I've been able to figure out this only, How can I get whole JSON Object and JSON Object by User Id?

Comment: are you familiar with the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` Method? tons of examples online on how to do this.. have you tried a google search for starters ?

Comment: @MethodMan Why would you do the JSON conversion yourself in an ApiController? The framework handles that for you.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813280/6522459, instead of returning datetime return your list

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, I've browsed the internet and SO and found tons of example but it's not fulfilling my need

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem that's for MVC...this question is about Web API. Web API will return JSON automatically if you just return an object

Comment: @ADyson Can you please demonstarte an example based on question

Comment: "How can I get whole JSON Object and JSON Object by User Id?"...you need two action methods. One which returns the whole list of users, and one which accepts a user ID as input, selects that whole user and returns it as a single object. To return an object/list as JSON, you don't need to do anything special in Web API, just return the object and .NET will take care of the conversion.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, but as pointed I'm completely new to C# so I have very little idea of how to implement this

Comment: Study this first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api . It should give you the patterns you need in order to answer your questions. The "GetAllProducts()" and "GetProduct(int id)" method in the first code example are analogous to what you're describing (get all users and get a single user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example how to return json response from webapi controller

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all Persons
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>     
    [HttpGet]
    // GET: api/User/GetAll
    [Route("api/User/GetAll")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetData()
    {
        return Ok(PersonDataAccess.Data);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get Person By ID
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Person id </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    // GET: api/User/GetByID/5
    [Route("api/User/GetByID/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        PersonDataAccess person = PersonDataAccess.Data.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id = id);
        if (person != null)
        {
            return Ok(person);
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
}
```

[Check this from more information about response types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results)

Comment: Ok that's better. But what about the "JSON Object by User Id?" part of the question?

Comment: if you mean get by id check answer

Comment: You should still add a textual explanation to your answer, rather than just a raw code dump.

Comment: @YashKaranke That's just how ASP.NET Web API routing works. You should [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem This works perfectly but how do I map it with Address?

Comment: @mason yes mason, I intend to.

Comment: @YashKaranke You should add the explanation *before* you post. Not after.

Comment: @YashKaranke your static data doesn't have Address.
are you going to get data from database using ef  or some thing like that?

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem It's coming from another file with the same schema as `PersonDataAccess`

Comment: if you are using json file you can do it like attached link https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem thanks for the reference but I'm getting type conversion error here  `PersonDataAccess person = PersonDataAccess.Data.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id = (id));`

Comment: @AhmedGhoniem No, I'm not using JSON file, I'm using .cs which contains schema as same as given the question

Answer (score -1):

Inside your data access class

```
class PersonDataAccess
{
    ...

    public IList<Person> GetData (int id) => Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

}
```

inside your controller

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetData(int id)
{
    var result = (new PersonDataAccess ()).GetData(id);

    if (result == null)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(result);
}
```