# A simple user name and password login using ajax, jquery and asp.net core

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to make a simple user login using `ajax`, `jquery` and `asp.net core 2.1`. I already have an `sql` database with username and password in place. The user should login using his/her `username` and `password`, after which they'll be directed to a certain page `DemoGrid/ShowGrid`. Now, this is for learning the purpose, not for production, so i am not using any form of authentication, or considering security much.
I just want the user to login, password, and username checked, and if valid redirected to a specific page.
Here's my `index.cshtml`:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 alert alert-info">
        <h3 class="text-center"> Login</h3>
        <form id="loginForm">
            <div id="msg">
                <ul style="color:red;">Invalid Username or Password</ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username"
                           id="logUsername" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password"
                           id="logPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit" onclick="Login()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Login </i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my ajax code:

```
$("#msg").hide();
var Login = function () {
    var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type="post",
        url="/Login/Validate",
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.status == false) {
                $("#loginForm")[0].reset();
                $("#msg").show();
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "DemoGrid/ShowGrid";
                $("#msg").hide();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

I also have a login model in place :

```
namespace ExampleGrid.Models
{
    [Table("PrintLogins", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class UserLogin
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a controller `LoginController.cs`:

```
namespace ExampleGrid.Controllers
{
    //[Route("api/[controller]")]
    // [ApiController]


    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private DatabaseContext _context;

        public LoginController(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Validate([FromBody] UserLogin user)
        {
            var login = _context.UserLogin.Where(s => s.username == 
                user.password);
            if (login.Any())
            {
                if (login.Where(s => s.password == user.password).Any())
                {

                    return Json(new { status = true, message = "Login 
                        Successfull!" });
                }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { status = true, message = "Invalid 
                    Password!" });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { status = false, message = "Invalid Username!" 
              });
        }
    }
```

Now here's where i am stuck. I have googled, and tried several options, but nothing works for me so far. In the above code, i am having a red line under `Json`..of course that means an error `the name Json doesn't exist in the current contex`. So if any one has a way of doing this, and an explanation to a working solution, i'd really appreciate. I am still learning and would like to learn as much as possible so a variety of solutions are welcomed.

code to the related page `DemoGrid/ShowGrid`:

```
<div style="width:100%; margin:0 auto;">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt- 
        responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Might this be related? [CS0103 C# The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272203/cs0103-c-sharp-the-name-json-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context).

Comment: Also try `new JsonResult(new{ status=true, message="...."})`

Comment: @showdev I change my controller from `LoginController: ControllerBase` to `LoginController: Controller` ..but the ajax and controller are not communicating ...and i get this error on the console `missing : after property id` and `Login is not defined`...could there be a problem with my ajax code  ?

Comment: @itminus i tried that too, no results yet...same outcome as my comment above

Comment: @RayOjuka use `return Ok(...)`, or the other methods to return different status codes.

Comment: @RayOjuka Did you get this error when you click the button to submit the form? Could you please share us the complete code of related pages?

Comment: @juunas at what point should i `return Ok()`...mind explaining more?

Comment: Instead of return Json(). That function exists in the "classic" asp.net MVC, but it does not exist in Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `Json()` is a helper method defined in the `Controller` class. If you don't like to make your controller inherit from the `Controller` class, you could return a `new JsonResult(new{ status=true, message="...."})`
2. Besides, there's also a syntax error in your ajax code, fix it in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
    type="post",
    type:"post",
    url="/Login/Validate",
    url:"/Login/Validate",
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.status == false) {
            $("#loginForm")[0].reset();
            $("#msg").show();
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "DemoGrid/ShowGrid";
            $("#msg").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

3. Finally, by using a `[FromBody]` attribute in your action method, your server is expecting that the whole request body is able to be deserialized to `UserLogin`. Typically, this requires that the `Content-Type` is `application/json`, but your ajax is sending a `form-url-encoded` payload. So one approach is to change the action method in the following way:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Validate([FromBody] UserLogin user)
        public ActionResult Validate(UserLogin user)
        {
            var login = _context.UserLogin.Where(s => s.username == user.password);
            ...
        }
```

---

Or if you prefer `JSON` format, you need change your ajax as below:

```
        var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
        var data = new FormData(document.querySelector("#loginForm"));
        var payload = {};
        data.forEach((v,k) => payload[k] = v);
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"/Login/Validate",
            contentType:"application/json",
            data: data,
            data: JSON.stringify(payload), 
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status == false) {
                    $("#loginForm")[0].reset();
                    $("#msg").show();
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = "DemoGrid/ShowGrid";
                    $("#msg").hide();
                }
            }
        })
```

And the action method will be the same as yours:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate([FromBody] UserLogin user)
    {
        var login = _context.UserLogin.Where(s => s.username == user.password);
        ...        
    }
```

Comment: i went with the second option, but when i test with the break point, it doesn't get to the `if` statement...any solution to that?

Comment: @RayOjuka What's the "result"  when you test with the break point?

Comment: @RayOjuka Here the "result" means the parameter in the function: `function (result) { if (result.status == false) { ... }  else { ... }`

Comment: I get this warning `The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type`

Comment: @RayOjuka what's the result returned by the server?

Comment: Server does't return anything. but when i check at the parameters, i can see the password passed...where the server is to return successful or invalid, it skips

Comment: @RayOjuka Do you mean the action method is never hit even the ajax is successfully  sent to `/Login/Validate` ?

Comment: @RayOjuka I've tested my code, it works fine for me. Is your code exactly the same as mine? If it still doesn't work, could you upload your complete sample code to GitHub or somewhere else?

Comment: I figure out the problem was with my if statement `Invalid Password!` should have been `false`, i had it as `true`...and i was pointing at a login view, and not a login table....now all is functioning as expected. I really appreciate for holding up to this time, and the much you've showed me. Thanks man!